# How can I compare 3 values in an array to "not" or "all" equal each other?

Tags: arrays, swift

**The Problem:**

I'm building the game [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)) and I therefore have to choose 3 cards on the board. 
Each of these cards have four different properties on it:

- Color (number between 0 and 2)
- Shape (number between 0 and 2)
- Shade (number between 0 and 2)
- Number (number between 0 and 2)

Now I want to compare 3 chosen cards to each other and compute if they are a match or not. I can't just get my head around that because I want to also write it in a good way and not with dozens of for loops.

So we have a match if:

- All 4 properties are equal to each other on every card

  - Card 1 has red, triangle, 2, striped and Card 2 + 3 also have red, triangle, 2, striped
- 4 properties are different to each other on every card

  - if card 1 has red, triangly, 2, striped no other card can have one of these

**The Assignment**

So now I should invent a solution that "according to the teacher" is very simple and my model for this app shouldn't be more then 100 lines of code. Now I'm at almost 100 lines of code and I need to do some more stuff. So I should implement this in a very DRY way.

***How would you tackle this problem***

I need some guidance to guide me into the right direction. 
***Is there some built in method for arrays I'm missing in Swift or do I need to implement some kind of protocol***

Comment: Could you add the code defining the class card? and the code that you've tried so far, it would make your question clearer.

Comment: How is color a number between 0 and 2?

Comment: @Sweeper I should implement the model in a way it’s unrelated to any view. So my idea is to just give everything a number and the view controller can decide how to name it. Or is this a bad idea ?

Comment: Your description of a “set match” might be misleading. For each of the four properties, the three values of the cards must be all same or all identical. Three cards which are all red and solid, but have all different colors and numbers, form a valid set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Remark:* The following solution is tailored for the special case of
the Set game, where all three values are 0, 1, or 2. It would not help
to check if three *arbitrary* values are all equal or all different.)

A bit of mathematics helps. If you have three integers x, y, z in the range from
0 to 2, then x+y+z is a multiple of 3 if (and only if)

- x, y, z are all equal, or
- x, y, z are all different.

This can be checked with

```
if (x + y + z) % 3 == 0 {
    // x, y, z are all equal or all different.
}
```

Therefore, if the `Card` type is defined as

```
struct Card {
    let number: Int // 0, 1, 2
    let symbol: Int // 0, 1, 2
    let shade:  Int // 0, 1, 2
    let color:  Int // 0, 1, 2
}
```

then the check for a valid set is quite efficiently done with:

```
func isValidMatch(c1: Card, c2: Card, c3: Card) -> Bool {
    return (c1.number + c2.number + c3.number) % 3 == 0
        && (c1.symbol + c2.symbol + c3.symbol) % 3 == 0
        && (c1.shade + c2.shade + c3.shade) % 3 == 0
        && (c1.color + c2.color + c3.color) % 3 == 0
}
```

Alternatively, define enumerations with raw values in the range 0, 1, 2 for the various properties:

```
struct Card {

    enum Number: Int {
        case one, two, three
    }

    enum Symbol: Int {
        case diamond, squiggle, oval
    }

    enum Shade: Int {
        case solid, striped, open
    }

    enum Color: Int {
        case red, green, purple
    }

    let number: Number
    let symbol: Symbol
    let shade: Shade
    let color: Color
}


func isValidMatch(c1: Card, c2: Card, c3: Card) -> Bool {
    return (c1.number.rawValue + c2.number.rawValue + c3.number.rawValue) % 3 == 0
        && (c1.symbol.rawValue + c2.symbol.rawValue + c3.symbol.rawValue) % 3 == 0
        && (c1.shade.rawValue + c2.shade.rawValue + c3.shade.rawValue) % 3 == 0
        && (c1.color.rawValue + c2.color.rawValue + c3.color.rawValue) % 3 == 0
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks that is the most elegant solution I was looking for. Someone over on reddit already got me the tip of using a modulo operator but not how. Now I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Card` class should conform to the [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol:

```
class Card : Equatable {
    let color: Int
    let shape: Int
    let shade: Int
    let number: Int

    //This is a failable initializer (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) since we haven't used enums like in another answer, which are safer. 
    init?(color: Int, shape: Int, shade: Int, number: Int) {
        //make sure that all properties are between 0 and 2
        guard 0...2 ~= color, 0...2 ~= shape, 0...2 ~= shade, 0...2 ~= number else {
            fatalError("All properties should be integers between 0 and 2")
        }
        self.color = color
        self.shape = shape
        self.shade = shade
        self.number = number
    }

    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color && lhs.shape == rhs.shape && lhs.shade == rhs.shade && lhs.number == rhs.number
    }
}
```

So you'll have equality when all four properties are equal. As noted by **@MartinR**: In Swift 4.1 and above, the compiler will synthesize the `==` operator automatically, and would suffice to declare conformance to the Equatable protocol.

To conform to the Equatable protocol, all you have to do is implement this function:

```
static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool
```

Now if you want to check that 3 cards are equal, use the `==` operator:

```
let c1 = Card(color: 2, shape: 1, shade: 0, number: 1)
let c2 = Card(color: 2, shape: 1, shade: 0, number: 1)
let c3 = Card(color: 2, shape: 1, shade: 0, number: 1)
let c4 = Card(color: 2, shape: 1, shade: 0, number: 2)

(c1 == c2) && (c2 == c3)
```

Finally, if you want to have a function that compares three cards at a time, you could add this code to your `Card` class:

```
class func compareThreeCards(firstCard: Card, secondCard: Card, thirdCard: Card) -> Bool {
    return (firstCard == secondCard) && (secondCard == thirdCard)
}
```

And you could use it like so:

```
Card.compareThreeCards(firstCard: c1!, secondCard: c2!, thirdCard: c3!)
```

Comment: Note that as of Swift 4, the compiler synthesizes the `==` operator automatically, it suffices to declare conformance to the `Equatable` protocol.

Comment: @MartinR you mean Swift 4.1?

Comment: Yes, Swift 4.1 (which comes with the current Xcode 9.4.1)

Comment: I've inserted your note in the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You are missing the concept of a match in the game Set.  The three cards are all unique.  You look at each property in turn.  They match if they all share the same value for each property or are all different for each property.

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 4.1, structs and enums can have Equatable and Hashable for free (not for Classes).

So for example, if you have a Card struct, just make this type hashable, create a set with your cards, and just compare them.

```
struct Card: Hashable {

    var color: Int
    var shape: Int
    var shade: Int
    var number: Int
}

let card1 = Card(color: 2, shape: 2, shade: 2, number: 0)
let card2 = Card(color: 2, shape: 2, shade: 2, number: 1)
let card3 = Card(color: 3, shape: 1, shade: 0, number: 2)


print(card1 == card2 && card2 == card3) // Prints false, all different.

let card4 = Card(color: 1, shape: 2, shade: 0, number: 0)
let card5 = Card(color: 1, shape: 2, shade: 0, number: 0)
let card6 = Card(color: 1, shape: 2, shade: 0, number: 0)

print(card4 == card5 && card5 == card6) // Prints true, all the same.
```

Note(Thanks to Leo Dabus): Set it is an unordered collection.

Comment: The initializer it is also not needed when using a struct. Btw better to declare all properties as constants. If you need to change it later just create a new object.

Comment: Note that set it is an unordered collection

Comment: You are missing the concept of a match in the game Set. The three cards are all unique. You look at each property in turn. They match if they all share the same value for each property or are all different for each property.

Comment: I believe you won't lose the uniqueness of your cards if you use set only to compare the cards.

Comment: vacawama, I changed it to avoid confusion. I hope this can help you.