# How to simplify this Swift code with closures

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a  [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)) game, where 3 cards make a Set only when each of their attributes is the same, or is different.

```
import Foundation

struct Card {
    var shape: Variant
    var numberOfShapes: Variant
    var shading: Variant
    var color: Variant

    enum Variant: Int {
        case one = 1
        case two
        case three

        static var all: [Variant] { return [.one, .two, .three] }
    }


}

extension Card {

    static func isSet(cards: [Card]) -> Bool {
        if cards.count == 3 {

            var shapeMakesSet: Bool {
                if cards[0].shape.rawValue == cards[1].shape.rawValue && cards[0].shape.rawValue == cards[2].shape.rawValue {
                    return true
                } else if cards[0].shape.rawValue != cards[1].shape.rawValue && cards[0].shape.rawValue != cards[2].shape.rawValue && cards[1].shape.rawValue != cards[2].shape.rawValue  {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking of creating 4 `Bool` variables for each attribute inside `isSet` but this doesn't seem to be a good idea. It would probably work, but would take lots of lines. Is there any way I can simplify it using closures or something else?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081088/how-can-i-compare-3-values-in-an-array-to-not-or-all-equal-each-other.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that helps a lot!

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you don't need `all` in your `Variant` `enum`, if you make it conform to `CaseIterable`, you get it for free in the static variable `allCases`.